# Python, default keyword arguments after variable length positional arguments

Tags: python, variadic-functions, python-2.x, named-parameters, default-parameters

I thought I could use named parameters after variable-length positional parameters in a function call in Python 2, but I get a `SyntaxError` when importing a python class. I'm writing with the following "get" method, for example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "You have created a Foo."

    def get(self, *args, raw=False, vars=None):
        print len(args)
        print raw
        print vars
```

The error looks like:

```
def get(self, *args, raw=False, vars=None):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'd like to be able to call the method several ways:

```
f = Foo()
f.get(arg1, arg2)
f.get(arg1, raw=True)
f.get(arg1, arg2, raw=True, vars=something)
```

etc.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It does work, but only in Python 3. See PEP [3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/). From glancing over the "what's new" documents, it seems that there is no 2.x backport, so you're out of luck. You'll have to accept any keyword arguments (`**kwargs`) and manually parse it. You can use `d.get(k, default)` to either get `d[k]` or `default` if that's not there. To remove an argument from `kwargs`, e.g. before calling a super class' method, use `d.pop`.

---

Note that in `def get(self, *args, raw=False, vars=None):`, the `raw=False` and `vars=None` have nothing to do with keyword arguments. Those are default argument values. Arguments with a default value may be passed positionally, and arguments without a default value may be passed by keyword:

```
def f(a=1): pass
f(2)  # works, passing a positionally
def f(a): pass
f(a=2)  # works, passing a by keyword
```

Similarly, keyword-only arguments are not required to have a default value. Coming after the `*args` argument is what marks them as keyword-only, not the presence of a default value:

```
def f(*args, a): pass
# a is a mandatory, keyword-only argument
```

Comment: Thanks both to you and Imran!  Your answer with Imran's code block and docstring suggestion answered the question perfectly.

Answer (score 51):

Python's syntax doesn't allow variable args in function and keyword arguments with default value at the same time. If you must have keyword arguments along with arbitrary number of positional arguments, you need to allow arbitrary number of keyword arguments as well.

This is a common pattern to provide default values for keyword arguments, as well as allowing any number of positional arguments:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
   raw = kwargs.pop('raw', False)
   vars = kwargs.pop('vars', None)
```

If you don't use the extra keyword arguments at all, you have nothing to worry about. This makes the function a bit less self-documenting, which you can make up with a properly written docstring.