# Python: Pass function to function with named parameters

Tags: python

I am looking to pass a function to another function, as well as a named parameter. This is similar to [the question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803616/passing-functions-with-arguments-to-another-function-in-python), except that it doesn't address named parameters. A question was asked about it in the comments but no reply.

Example:

```
def printPath(path, displayNumber = False):
    pass

def explore(path, function, *args):
    contents = function(*args)

print explore(path, printPath, path, displayNumber = False)
```

This gives the error:

```
TypeError: explore() got an unexpected keyword argument 'displayNumber'
```

Comment: A more relevant question that is already discussed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940180/python-default-keyword-arguments-after-variable-length-positional-arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to allow `explore` to receive named parameters as well:

```
def printPath(path, displayNumber = False):
    pass

def explore(path, function, *args, **kwargs):
    contents = function(*args, **kwargs)

print explore(path, printPath, path, displayNumber = False)
```