# SyntaxError using *args and **kwargs in an __init__ in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to define a class `RecurringInterval` which uses the `rrule` class from `dateutil.rrule` through composition, and in addition has the attribute `period` which by default is `None`. I've tried to initialize it in this way:

```
class RecurringInterval(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, period=None, **kwargs):
        self.period = period
        self.rrule = dateutil.rrule.rrule(*args, **kwargs)

recurring_interval = RecurringInterval(dateutil.rrule.DAILY, count=1)
```

However, I get a `SyntaxError`:

```
  File "/home/kurt/dev/scratch/Furion_scheduler/recurring_interval.py", line 7
    def __init__(self, *args, period=None, **kwargs):
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As I understand it, positional arguments should come before keyword arguments, so this is how I would expect the syntax to be; how would I correct it? (From https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists this is not yet clear to me).

I tried bringing `period=None` forward, like so:

```
class RecurringInterval(object):
    def __init__(self, period=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.period = period
        self.rrule = dateutil.rrule.rrule(*args, **kwargs)
```

but this gives rise to a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kurt/dev/scratch/Furion_scheduler/recurring_interval.py", line 9, in <module>
    recurring_interval = RecurringInterval(dateutil.rrule.DAILY, count=1)
  File "/home/kurt/dev/scratch/Furion_scheduler/recurring_interval.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.rrule = dateutil.rrule.rrule(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

How can I initialize the `RecurringInterval` in the intended fashion?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? I think you can definitely do what you're trying to do there in python 3, but might not be possible in 2. The docs you're referring to are covering function calling rather than function definition.

Comment: [Hammerite](http://stackoverflow.com/users/340819/hammerite), I'm using Python 2. With the `__init__` as `__init__(self, period=None, *args, **kwargs)`, I tried running the code in Python 3, but I then get `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'freq'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Following [Python, default keyword arguments after variable length positional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940180/python-default-keyword-arguments-after-variable-length-positional-arguments), the following works in Python 3:

```
class RecurringInterval(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, duration=datetime.timedelta(seconds=0), **kwargs):    # Initializing in this way only works in Python 3
        self.duration = duration
        self.rrule = dateutil.rrule.rrule(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Old answer**

Following this [Github article](https://github.com/kevinjqiu/btsync.py/issues/10), I found a solution using `kwargs.pop`:

```
class RecurringInterval(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.period = kwargs.pop('period', None)
        self.rrule = dateutil.rrule.rrule(*args, **kwargs)

recurring_interval = RecurringInterval(dateutil.rrule.DAILY, count=1, period=datetime.timedelta(days=2))
```

This way, `period` is given as a keyword argument, it is assigned to `self.period`, the default value of which is `None`, while the remaining `args` and `kwargs` are used to initialize the `RecurringInterval`'s `self.rrule`.

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
def __init__(self, period=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Daniel, I tried this, but it leads to a `TypeError` rather than a `SyntaxError` (see the latter part of the question). How would I 'totally' fix the code?

Comment: @KurtPeek that's another different error than your question